# GuzzleHttp\Client cURL error 18: transfer closed

Tags: curl, guzzle, laravel-6

I am using `GuzzleHttp\Client` Laravel 6 and I am getting this error when I am trying to get Data from API, it's working fine on postman

Here is My Code

```
try {
        $client = new Client();
        $result = $client->request("POST", $this->url,
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->ApiToken
                ],
            ]);
        $content = $result->getBody()->getContents();
        return [
            'bool' => true,
            'message' => 'Success',
            'result' => $content,
        ];

    }  catch (\Exception  $exception) {
        return [
            'bool' => false,
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];
    }
```

getting this error

```
cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue , Maybe it will help someone

```
 $client = new Client();
    $result = $client->request("POST", $this->url,
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->ApiToken,
                'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate', //new line added
            ],
        ]);
    $content = $result->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: added but not working with laravel valet

Answer (score 1):

The error code 18

> cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

as specified by curl errors,

> CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE (18)
> A file transfer was shorter or larger than expected. This happens when the
> server first reports an expected transfer size, and then delivers data that
> does not match the previously given size.

since it is receiving a chunked encoding stream it knows when there is data left in a chunk to receive. When the connection is closed,curl tells that the last received chunk was incomplete. Thus you get this error code.

#### Why adding a Accept Encoding with gzip compression format works?

To solve the above problem we need a encode the data to preserve the packets to receive all of it, HTTP headers provides encoding and for the client i.e you to tell the server which encoding is supported, then the server responds accordingly and informs the client of its choice with the Content-Encoding response header.

```
'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,                      deflate                   br'
                     encoding technique       compression format(zlib)  providing one more compression format as alternate to the server
```

```
$result = $client->request("POST", $this->url,
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->ApiToken,
                'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br', //add encoding technique
            ],
        ]);
    $content = $result->getBody()->getContents();
```